# Error in Autoload.php

Tags: autoloader

I am facing below error while I am trying to insert a product through Magento Admin Panel.

```
2017-02-27T15:49:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Productslider/Model/Source/Feature.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/prod/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2017-02-27T15:49:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Productslider/Model/Source/Feature.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/prod/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2017-02-27T15:49:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Productslider/Model/Source/Feature.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/prod/public_html/app/code/local:/home/prod/public_html/app/code/community:/home/prod/public_html/app/code/core:/home/prod/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/prod/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

I refreshed cache. I tried to find out `Mage_Productslider.xml`  in `app/etc/modules/`. But there is no such file.

How can I remove the error ?

Screenshot of `app/code/community` and `app/code/local`

[image]

Comment: To find the module search for `Productslider` inside `app/etc/modules`.

Comment: @JonathanRibas there is nothing like that. Thanks.

Comment: Can you search for `Productslider` inside `app/code/community/` and `app/code/local/`?

Comment: Thanks @JonathanRibas. I added the screenshot of `app/code/community/ ` and `app/code/local/`. I think I installed any extension before. After that I uninstalled the extension. But the extension left some `files` or `code` in the Magento System. Is it possible to find out this `files` or `code` ?

Comment: Search for the word `Productslider` inside all folders and files of  `app/code/community/` and `app/code/local/`.
Don't forget do delete your Magento cache `var/cache/`

Comment: @JonathanRibas, I tried your way but could not fine any solution. thanks

Comment: Can you search recursively for the file `Feature.php` in `app/code/community/` and `app/code/local/`?

Answer (score 0):

There must be module installed for product slider. Clean all instance of Productslider by find all feature of the editor. It will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Amit Sankhala. `Clean all instance of Productslider by find all feature of the editor.` How can I do that ?